# How to force value a span or div to the right side?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

How to force value `20%` and `70%` be at right side instead of left like image below?
I am trying to use `float-right` but it is not perfectly be inline with left status.

[image]

HTML

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-lg-6 col-md-12'>
        <span class='text-white'>Planned Start</span>
    </div>
    <div class='col-lg-6 col-md-12'>
        <span class='text-white mt-20'>%</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're saying you want the green to come from the right instead of the left of the progress bar? I guess I don't totally understand the question

Comment: Try adding text-right to parent div of % 
https://codepen.io/rohinikumar4073/pen/QWbzGpv

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy, yeah thanks..